# Print akka version in Play Framework 2.4.1

Tags: version, akka, playframework-2.4

How can I get the current akka version in Play Framework 2.4.1? I've searched on all configuration files and I don't see any akka dependecy (although I can use akka in Play).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within activator, use `show compile:dependencyClasspath` and you'll get a list of all jars used at compile time.

It's ugly and unformatted, but it works.

If you want to have something more structured, you can install [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to get more control.

- Shut down activator
- Add the following to `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`

  `addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.5")`
- Add the following to `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`

  `net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings`

You'll then have a bunch of different dependency-related tasks available in sbt/activator, such as `dependency-graph`.